# How to append to the lines with fewer columns in a tab separated text file?

Tags: bash, text, awk, sed, text-processing

I have a tab separated text file. Some rows have 10 columns and some rows have 11 columns. I want to add an extra column to the last of 10 column rows with the value 0. How can i do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have mentioned append, you can `awk` as below

```
awk -F $'\t' 'BEGIN {OFS = FS} NF==10{$0=$0"0"}1' input-file
```

The `-F $'\t'` takes care of the tab-separation part, `BEGIN {OFS = FS}` for setting the output field separation.

The `NF==10` looks only for the lines having only 10 records and the `{$0=$0"0"}1` for reconstructing that line with the extra word added.

To write to a separate file use the `>` redirect operator as

```
awk -F $'\t' 'BEGIN {OFS = FS} NF==10{$0=$0"0"}1' input-file > output-file
```

To replace the original  file use `mv`

```
awk -F $'\t' 'BEGIN {OFS = FS} NF==10{$0=$0"0"}1' input-file > output-file ; mv output-file input-file
```

Or if you have latest `GNU Awk` (since `4.1.0` released), it has the option of "inplace" file editing:

```
gawk -i inplace -F $'\t' 'BEGIN {OFS = FS} NF==10{$0=$0"0"}1' input-file
```

Comment: if I run this command it would modify the file? Or should I save the output of this command? Because when I exactly paste this command it started to display the content on the bash

Comment: @RaminZahedi : refer my update which tells you how to save to a new file

Comment: Actually I do not want to save to a new file, I want to modify this file. if the first command just modifies the input-file, why it outputs the content to the shell?

Comment: @RaminZahedi awk does not do in place editing by default. It just writes to stdout. To do in place editing you need to use gawk. What is your requirement? Use the same file?

Comment: my file is a 30 GB text file that I want to import to a postgresql table. but since for some rows the last column is missing i want to modify the file before importing, so, can i just modify this one or should I save the output to the new one?

Comment: Do you have gawk , check awk --version? Refer my update for replacing the original file?

Comment: Yes I have gawk. which one is faster? your last command in your answer or using gawk? if gawk, how should i use it?

Comment: Thanks and merry Xmas!

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work. I'm trying to figure out why. some of columns have null values. can it cause problem?

Comment: @RaminZahedi : Yes it can. My logic appends the 11th field only if it has non empty 10 fields.

Comment: @RaminZahedi : NF in the above command represents the number of non empty fields. Tweak my solution depending upon how many fields you want to have. And why did you remove the acceptance?

Comment: most of the rows have 11 columns separated by tab. the value for some of these columns is null but the tabs exist.

Comment: I remove the acceptance because it seems that it doesn't work for columns with null values. I want others to post their solutions

Comment: @RaminZahedi : a column is valid only if it is non empty. You can't call it 11 when there are empty fields between

Comment: the "tabs" still exist. PostgreSQL recognizes these columns and adds null values

Comment: @RaminZahedi : so just a confirmation again, you want to replace all the empty fields tab separated with zero?

Comment: Can you try awk 'BEGIN { FS = OFS = "\t" } { for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) if($i ~ /^ *$/) $i = 0 }; 1' file

Comment: No. empty fileds is okey, the problem is some rows have 10 columns instead of 11

Comment: @Inian- IMHO, In your very first solution I think in spite of doing $0=$0"0" we could do print $0 0;next rest we could let it be as same, because file is 30 GB long so in spite of reconstructing $0(current line) we could directly print the line and off course next keyword will allow us to skip further statements execution after it.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 's/[^\t]+/&/11;t;s/$/\t0/' file
```

This replaces the eleventh column with itsself otherwise it adds a tab and then `0`.