# How to remove the lines with fewer columns in a tab separated text file?

Tags: bash, text, awk, sed, grep

I have a tab separated text file with 11 columns (for some rows the value of some columns includes null value). Some rows have fewer columns. I want to remove rows with fewer columns. How can i do this?

Comment: read [ask] then try again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you can just use awk to filter out lines where `NF` is not 11:

```
awk -F'\t' 'NF == 11' file
```

Comment: Does NF==11 work if they are empty fields just tab separated? OP has an input like that based in his previous similar question.

Comment: @Inian since the input field separator has been changed to a single tab, empty fields still count. If the `FS` were used, then multiple consecutive blank characters would be treated as a single field separator.

Comment: but does this take care of output field separation as a single tab?

Comment: It doesn't touch the fields, so the rows with 11 fields aren't modified. I didn't see the previous question but if there's some prior knowledge assumed, then this one should be edited.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41313768/5291015, was my answer  to a similar OP, he "un accepted" the answer claiming it had empty fields within and didn't work for the NF==10 condition? Care to let know if am missing some thing here.

Comment: Hmm, I don't really know what the OP is trying to do any more!

Answer (score 2):

If you have a tab delimited file such as:

```
$ cat foo
1       2       3
4               6
7
```

or more vividly:

```
1\t2\t3
4\t\t6
7\t\t
```

your field count is still 3 for each record:

```
$ awk -F'\t' '{print NF}' foo
3
3
3
```

If you want to print the records which have no empty fields:

```
$ awk -F'\t' '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if($i=="") next}1' foo
1       2       3
```

Comment: in my file most of the rows have 11 columns but some of them actually have 10 columns (I'm not talking about null values, both of those rows may contain some null values). How can I remove the rows with fewer columns?

Comment: Using @TomFenech's solution. Does that not work for you?

Answer (score 0):

This Perl code does exactly what you want:

a) It ignores lines that whose field count doesn't equal what we want

b) It ignores lines that have empty fields

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
my ($fields, $f, $n, $size);
my $NUM_FIELDS = 11;
while (<STDIN>) {
  chomp;
  @fields = split(/,/, $_);
  next if $#fields + 1 != $NUM_FIELDS;
  $n = 0;
  foreach $f (@fields) {
    break if length($f) == 0;
    $n++;
  }
  printf("%s\n", $_) if ($n == $NUM_FIELDS);
}
```

Comment: I dont want to ignore rows with null values! almost all of the rows have some null values. I just want ignore rows with fewer columns than others. and I want modify the file in place.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/[^\t]\+/&/11;t;d' file
```

This replaces the eleventh non-tab character(s) with itsself or deletes the line.